# Dynamic Multiple dropdown select options from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to come up with some sort solution to a problem where I have to provide a user with dynamic dropdowns depending on the options they choose.

Currently I have 3 tables that are normalized as such.

[image: Tables]

Currently this works well with my HTML select elements, where if I select John Doe I would get Paul, Kevin and Dick as my second options and if I were to choose Kevin I would get Drake and Kanye as a third option.

My issue is that I do not want to keep creating tables since I would like to add more layers of staff_level in my application.

How would I approach this and have a fully dynamic table structure using PHP and MySQL?

Thank you for taking your time to read this.

Comment: What is the situation in which these multiple-level tables are being used? What is the relationship between John Johns and Paul Pete and Kevin Mayor?

Comment: Hi @AaronD the tables I provided highlight the relationship between the names? what additional relationship data are you looking for?

Comment: I'll rephrase - why did you design it this way? What real-world relationship is there between those names? I'm thinking that a different design might be more appropriate, simply because I'm having difficulty imagining a scenario in which there is a tree of relationships like this (other than perhaps a family tree). A relationship table might be a better fit.

Comment: For example - a single Staff table with fields `id` and `name`, and then a `StaffRelationships` table (for example maybe it's a manager-subordinate type relationship) with fields `ManagerId` and `SubordinateId` where you put the ids in. That way every person has a unique id and you can have many-to-many relationships between them.

Comment: Hi @AaronD that is the question really, how can I improve this? The scenario would if I wanted to find who Kanye South reports to, in this case it would be Dick Ross, and if I wanted to also find out who Dick Ross reports too it would be Sam Smith. I'm basically trying to find a better way to create these relationships.

Comment: @AaronD I think that would be the best way to go, I'm just having a bit of trouble visualizing it. Could you throw up an example for me to check out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72593/discussion-between-aaron-d-and-baconjuice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an association table between the people. Put all of them in one table with unique IDs like so:

```
Table Staff
id  | Name        | <Other fields>
----+-------------+----------
1   | John Doe    | 
2   | Sam Smith   | 
3   | John Johns  | 
4   | Paul Pete   | 
5   | Kevin Mayor | 
6   | Dick Ross   | 
      ...
```

Then the association table named whatever you like - maybe StaffHeirarchy:

```
Table StaffRelationships
id | ManagerId | SubordinateId
---+-----------+--------------
*  | Null      | 1                       # Has no manager
*  | 2         | 6                       # Dick Ross is subordinate to Sam Smith
```

This table should have an id field for unique keys, but you don't have to care about what it is (it's not used as a Foreign Key as the `Staff.id` field is), which is why I put `*` there - in reality it would be some integer id.

I haven't seen your PHP for pulling values out of the database, but it is basically the same - query the association table filtering for the id of the manager you are looking for and you will get the ids of the subordinates (which you can `JOIN` on the staff table to get the names).

Comment: Makes Perfect sense! Thank you very much.